# How call validate before Devise sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, devise, validation

I would like to disable user's authorization where the date the account was created_at is in 2010.

How can I use callbacks for this task and how can I use it with Devise?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [`lockable`](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable) strategy in Devise?

If so, in the controller that is redirected to after logging in, you can add a before_filter that does something like this:

```rb
current_user.lock_access! if current_user && current_user.created_at.year == "2010"
```

And you also need to manually sign the user out, possibly with something like this:

```rb
sign_out current_user
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has 2 parts:

1. Based on some criteria (e.g. account creation date), you want to authorize users to perform certain actions
2. You want to use Devise for authentication

Note that there is a difference between authentication (you are who you say you are) and authorization (you are allowed to do what you're requesting), and they are typically implemented using different software.

For example, you can use Devise for authentication and CanCan to manage authorization (railscast on CanCan: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Using CanCan, you would simply allow users to perform action based on the `created_at` attribute for their account, and otherwise call Devise's `authorize!` method.

Comment: I using CanCan but how use created_at field for access in ability.rb ?

Comment: Something like `can :manage, Project if user.account.created_at.year < 2011` (more on defining abilities here: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan). Then catch the exception when a user isn't authorized (see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan at point 3).